Electric circuit breakers are switch on and off automatically
I'm facing strange problem at home. In normal course of electricity when there is no fluctuations in power circuit breakers are operating automatically means they switch off and after sometime automatically switch on. This behaviour has been seen for 32 AMP power circuit breaker and 16 AMP MCB/elcb.
I have seen these devices switching off but never seen switched on automatically.
I have checked all circuits.

Can you explain it better? how come a circuit breaker switches on automatically?

breakers should not switch on automatically ... such a behavior would be extremely dangerous to anyone working on the disconnected circuit

Where are you located? Do you by any chance have some sort of load management agreement with your utility? In some cases, these allow the utility to remotely switch off and on nonessential loads in the house.

No circuit breaker (MCB, MCCB, ELCB, RCCB, RCBO, RCD, or MPCB) will turn ON automatically . If you see the power turning on and off, either:
1. The breaker in your home is staying on and the power outside your home is intermittent (switching on and off).
In this case, there is nothing you can do about it. The fault is with your utility.
2. Someone else is flipping the breaker back on.
If you have any of the above breakers tripping regularly, there is a serious problem in your home you need to fix.
(If a breaker were to turn on automatically it would be a major safety hazard.)
